# find the complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute
$$\lim_{z \to 2e^{i\pi /3}} \frac{z^3+8}{z^4+4z^2+16}$$

Note that if we replace the value
$$(2e^{i\pi /3})^3+8=-8+8=0$$
and
$$(2e^{i\pi /3})^4+4(2e^{i\pi /3})^2+16=16(e^{i 4\pi /3}+e^{i 2\pi /3}+1)=16(-1+1)=0$$

So it is a case of $\frac{0}{0}$ of course my goal is not to use L'Hopital yet, but it should be possible to simplify the expression of the denominator, any suggestion to factor this? thanks for that

Comment: Did you try to facter both $z^3+8$ and $z^4+4z^2+16$ to the linear factors?

Comment: @LidingYao I guess my question is how to achieve this

Comment: This is abstract algebra but not complex analysis then. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=factorize+Power%5Bx%2C3%5D+%2B+8 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=factorize+Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%2B4Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B16 . WolframAlpha can provide you step by step solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an algorithm to find the GCD of two polynomials with rational coefficients.

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 4 x^{2}  + 16 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 8 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 4 x^{2}  + 16 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 8 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 8 x  + 16 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 8 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 8 x  + 16 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 2 }{ 4 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 2 }{ 4 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 2 x  + 4 }{ 4 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x  + 2 }{ 4 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 4 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{4 } \right)  -  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{confirming  GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 4 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 4 x^{2}  + 16 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 4 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 4 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 8 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 4 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 4 x^{2}  + 16 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{4 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 4 \right)  } $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 4 \right) }   $$

Now you divide out both numerator and denominator by the common factor $x^2 - 2x + 4$

Answer (score 1):

The [Factor Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Factor_theorem) establishes a correspondence between roots and linear factors. Let $p(z) = z^3 + 8$ and $q(z) = z^4 + 4z^2 +16$, so your rational function is $p(z)/q(z)$. Let's also name $\omega = 2\exp\frac{i\pi}{3} = 1 + i\sqrt{3}$.

When you check that $p(\omega) = 0$, that guarantees that $(z - \omega)$ is a factor of $p(z)$. In fact,
$$
p(z) = (z - \omega)(z^2 + \omega z + \omega^2).
$$
Similarly, since $q(\omega) = 0$,
$$
q(z) = (z - \omega)(z^3 + \omega z^2 + 2\omega z + 2\omega^2)
$$

Now, it's straightforward to evaluate the limit:
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to \omega} 
\frac{(z - \omega)(z^2 + \omega z + \omega^2)}{(z - \omega)(z^3 + \omega z^2 + 2\omega z + 2\omega^2)}
&= \lim_{z \to \omega} 
\frac{z^2 + \omega z + \omega^2}{z^3 + \omega z^2 + 2\omega z + 2\omega^2} \\
&= \frac{3\omega^2}{2\omega^3 + 4\omega^2} \\
&= \frac{3}{2\omega + 4}, 
\end{align}
which you can simplify further if you like.

Answer (score 0):

As you check both the numerator and denominator has zero (you can check they are simple), so you can factor out $(z-2e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}})$. Of course you can write $z^3+8=(z-2e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}})g(z)$, where $g(z)$ can be computed by long division.

On the other hand, write $x=2e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$, you can write the limit as $$\lim_{z\to w}\dfrac{\dfrac{z^3+8}{z-w}}{\dfrac{z^4+4z^2+16}{z-w}}=\dfrac{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to w}\dfrac{z^3+8}{z-w}}{\displaystyle\lim_{z\to w}\dfrac{z^4+4z^2+16}{z-w}}=\dfrac{\left.\dfrac{d}{dz}\right|_{z=w}(z^3+8)}{\left.\dfrac{d}{dz}\right|_{z=w}(z^4+4z^2+16)}$$
This is legal as both quotient has a removable singularity at $w$, so they have an analytic continuation, which means both limits exist. Choose the method you love.